# In Elastic Search how to apply score to dynamic array of Ids passed

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, search

I am trying to pass array of ids in a query and want to get the results in the same order of Ids in array. Number of elements in my array vary with each query. I see the below query with hardcoded ids work. But how can I make it work with array that changes on each request.

I found the below query from other reply here which is similar to my requirement but my elements in params are not fixed. How to give score to each element of array in order so that the original order is maintained.

```
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """for (int i = 0; i < params.scoring.length; i++) { if(doc['providerid'].value ==  params.scoring[i]['providerid']) return params.scoring[i]['score']; } return 0;""",
        "params": {
          "scoring": [
            {
              "providerid": 2000048977,
              "score": 1
            },
            {
              "providerid": 2000092892,
              "score": 2
            },
            {
              "providerid": 2000141299,
              "score": 3
            },
            {
              "providerid": 2000148861,
              "score": 4
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "providerid": [
       2000048977,
          2000092892,
          2000141299,
          2000148861
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a painless sort script like

```
"def index = 0, indexMap = new HashMap();" +
   "for (String str: params.ids) {" +
   "  shaIndexMap.put(str, index++);" +
   "}" +
   "if (doc[params.fieldName].size() == 0) {" +
   "  return Integer.MAX_VALUE;" +
   "}" +
   "for (int i = 0; i < doc[params.fieldName].length; ++i) {" +
   "  if (indexMap.containsKey(doc[params.fieldName][i])) {" +
   "    return shaIndexMap[doc[params.fieldName][i]];" +
   "  }" +
   "}" +
   "return Integer.MAX_VALUE;";

params.ids = ids you pass in the query
params.fieldName = field name of ES field (providerid)
```